# Are there any alternatives to Google Earth

Tags: java, google-maps, geolocation, wicket

I need to 'geo enable' a Java web application, and provide a facility allowing geographical points to be plotted on a world map. The catch is that the deployment sites do not have external Internet access. 
Google Earth Enterprise edition can be used in such a standalone environment, but costs the Earth.
Are there any lower cost or open source alternatives that I could look at?

Comment: Are you sure you mean Google Earth? It _sounds_ like Google Maps would be sufficient.

Comment: Open source comprehensive geo database and maps? If only.

Comment: Google Maps does not run offline. You have to connect to the public internet -- or to a Google Earth Enterprise server hosting a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other common mapping solutions, some are free some are not.

- NASA's WorldWind - Free but poorly documented
- ArcGis - I believe it costs but is extremely well supported and well documented
- FalconView - Free but I do not recall its ability to tie in other mapping sources

One of the three should suit your needs quite well. If you're looking for flat maps with street you might check out OpenStreetMap which could work for you also.

Comment: WorldWind is poorly documented but has LOTS of great examples in the SDK.  The corresponding terrain image server is also open source. You can download the terrain imagery and serve it up locally on your LAN.

Comment: I do agree with Tansir, it has lot of examples and uses JOGL for opengl rendering. You can do just about anything you would ever want in it, if you're willing to spend the time. I should probably mention that for free it's my first choice on desktop applications.

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointers to WorldWind. The map has to be embedded in a web page, and it looks like this is possible using the WorldWind applet interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think NASA had a SDK called World Wind...

Yes they do: http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth can actually run disconnected using a cache. The caches can be up to 2GBs in size -- which can actually cover a relatively large area at a reasonable level of detail.

You can make caches with the regular Google Earth client. The caches are compatible with both Google Earth and the Google Earth Javascript plugin. You can make caches with the plugin directly, however its limit is much lower than 2GBs -- I can't remember the exact number off the top of my head.

There are tools out there to make caches. Here's one I've looked at before:

http://bx11.110mb.com/gecacher.htm

-- Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can check OpenStreetMap (OSM) which is OpenSource. It is free alternative to GoogleMaps (so no GoogleEarth 3D features), but you can deploy OSM on your own serwer and use it only in your intranet.

Answer (score 0):

FalconView can cache its data and run offline.  Since it's designed for DoD use in the field, it naturally does very well offline.  You connect to a map source (GeoTIFF, etc.) and use the Map data Manager to copy your maps from an offline path to an online path.  The trick is getting map data that you can use.  See http://www.falconview.org/trac/FalconView/wiki/PublicDataSources for information on getting map data.  FalconView is open source.